# What does "that of" here mean?

Tags: meaning

> Wong said one charge - **that of** providing false information - brought against one of the organizers was for giving police the incorrect number for a street address, though the correct street name was provided.
>
> — [Reuters](http://www.reuters.com/article/2014/07/04/us-hongkong-protests-idUSKBN0F912320140704)

Is it just another way of saying *which is*? And does *those of* act in the same way with plural?

Comment: "one charge - that of providing false information .." is simply the way it is said. It is precise and helpful.

Comment: "Simply the way it is said", though helpful, is an observation rather than an analysis.  It can also be analyzed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using "that" is a way of avoiding repetition. Otherwise the sentence would be:

> One charge - the charge of providing false information ...

Instead of saying "that of", you can also say "the one of" or "namely". I find it difficult to use "which is" without the sentence sounding awkward or changing the meaning.

Since there were [4 different charges](http://www.theglobeandmail.com/news/world/hong-kong-police-charge-pro-democracy-march-organizers/article19461391/): failure to comply with instructions from a police officer, obstructing officers performing their duties, leaving a running vehicle and providing false information to an officer, if you refer to more than one, you can use "those of", just as you suggested:

> Two charges - those of leaving a running vehicle and providing false information ...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I feel that the sentence must have 'em-dashes' and not the hyphens that you typed there.

Now, answer to your second question - **No.** The *those of...* won't fit there because the sentence is about *a single charge* due to an act of providing false information.

Answer to the first question - yes. It may work *in this context.*

'Em-dashes' are used to replace commas here. You may simply remove those dashes and put commas along with your option *which is* and it'll convey the scene.

> Wong said one charge, which is providing false information, brought against one of the organizers was for giving police the incorrect number for a street address, though the correct street name was provided.

[Side note: I think it's an indirect speech and thus should have *that*. *Wong said that...* **If it's not,** it should have the quotes -  Wong said, "One charge, ..."]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a correct, simple and respected clause used to identify specific matters, especially in legal parlance.

And yes, a plural version can be made to work just as well:

"Wong said two charges - that of providing false information and that of assaulting a police officer- brought against one of the organizers..."

~or~

"Two pairs of shoes - those of the victim and those of the accused, were found at the scene of the crime."

Both of these examples are used to *specify* what is being referred to.

"Which is" might be used to describe something about a [charge] - but no, it cannot be used in the circumstance you describe.